# System instability + Memtest randomly shows error

Tags: ubuntu, memory, crash, memtest86+, memtest

i'm struggling with this problem where my ubuntu system (formerly BSODdding windows 7) is unstable.

I decided to perform several memtest runs and on 2 out of 4 I had errors. The first one happened on the first run

[image: First run]

Then, since I've 4x4GB  RAM sticks i perfomed these actions

- removed A+B and tested C+D - **no errors**
- replaced C+D with A+B - **no errors**
- moved A+B in the other 2 RAM slots in my MOBO - **no errors**
- replaced A+B with C+D - **no errors**

Hence i re-tried to test A+B+C+D (all positioned in their old slots) and memtest passed several runs across the 14hours i let the test running.

At this point I knew something was wrong but I had no time to perform other tests until a couple of days ago where I ran memtest for 12+hours without any errors.

I decided then to run it again yesterday overnight and when I woke up I found memtest showing this:

[image: yesterday's run]

As you can see the test giving error is #10 on both failing runs. Now I really don't know what to do and I'm probably misreading memtest results too.

**OTHER Infos**

My PC is composed by the following components:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i7-3770
- **MOBO**: ASUSTeK MAXIMUS V FORMULA Versione Rev 1.XX
- **RAM**: 4x4GB Corsair Vengeance CMZ16GX3M4A1600C9

I'm experiencing *several* Google Chrome Crashes along as Java crashes both during compilation and software usage (Intellij IDEA). It's worth mentioning that a laptop I own with the same software installed never (ever) crashes on java (both during compile-time and IDEA regular usage).

Also, sometimes, regular ubuntu applications such as FileManager crashes showing the beautiful "Ubuntu experienced an internal error" dialog.

I, a few times, tried to look into the java crash log and google it but I never came across anything letting me validate my thinking that this might be an hardware fault.

The Java crashes becomes more frequent (*with a "max" of one crash every 2 mins*) when the PC is powered-on for a long time (*probably cause i've several chrome -sucking ram- tabs open???*). Performing a `sudo echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` (clear ram cache) ***seems*** to delay next crash event.

Comment: I don't see where you replaced the bad module

Comment: Since i was unable to identify the bad module I didn't replace any!

Comment: You have 4GB modules?  The errors happen within the first module or first 4096 GB.  Given how cheap memory is you might consider just replacing all your modules so you have 32 GB.  Your problems are caused by bad modules though and will continue until you determine the culprit ( again likely Module A ).

Comment: Is the first module the first i see on my mobo from the left or the right? Also, 'm unsure if my mobo+cpu supports 32G even if i think it does. Furthermore, why doesn't the problem happen systematically?

Comment: Your motherboard and CPU both support 32GB.  Module A is clearly define in the manual.  It is going to be the first memory bank ( 1 of 2 ).

Comment: I wouldn't waste your money until you have some concrete evidence of what the problem is, especially given how expensive memory is right now. A few things I'd check first are a) your memory speed & configuration, b) run some CPU tests (e.g. Prime95) and c) See if temperature has any effect on making the problems better or worse. If the crashes occur "every few minutes" then simply booting and using the system with one memory stick removed at a time should narrow it down fairly quickly. If that doesn't isolate it, the problem may not be the RAM sticks at all.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq 'm testing with prime95 as we speak. regarding your checks. How can i check my memory speed? (i didn't change anything on bios level as far as I know) - about c) the temperature seems to not have any side-effects (so far)

Comment: Under Linux I'm not sure actually, under Windows I run CPU-Z. Some people suggest CPU-G though I've not tried it myself. Your motherboard should almost certainly show the values in the BIOS as well.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq using CPU-X i can see the clock is set to 1600MHz

Comment: Does it show any SPD, timing, or voltage information?

Comment: Nope i reboot into BIOS . it shows DRAM voltage set to 1.49 ( spiking to 1.5 occasionally) . timings are 9-9-9-24-2 i let prime ran 1.5h without errors ill let memtest go again overnight

Comment: ASUS mainboards don't really like  Corsair RAM. They often cause such strange errors. Is the RAM listed as compatible on ASUS home page?